# Where can I ask questions when I don't know which SE is the right one?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

On which SE should I ask a questions if I don't know which is the right place for it.

For example, I asked a question on Stackoverflow about websites with programming challenges (recommendation), because I couldn't find a website recommendation SE (like software recommendation) and thought it would fit into SO, but it didn't.

Second questions to this topic: Why are some normal questions put on hold because of off-topic when they are completely normal. First, as a new user, I was very insecure if my questions is right in that SE.

Comment: ^ that answers the first question. The second question is site-specific; for Stack Overflow you need to ask this on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

About your first question: Right here. Just make sure to use the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag when asking it.

Also, as was pointed out in comments, knowing what's on topic changes from site to site but you ask in that specific site's meta if the question you have would be on topic.